# Issues with SQL Server LIKE clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-like

I'm sure this is a VERY simple problem, but I've not been able to figure it out. Here's my query:

```
select column1 from table1 with(nolock)
where column1 like '2011-07-0[78]%'
order by column1 desc
```

As you can tell, I'm querying a row looking for timestamps that are from either today or yesterday.

A full timestamp within one of these rows looks like this:

> 2011-07-08 12:16:39.553

I've done similar things many times with no trouble, but the above query returns no results no matter what I try. (Yes, there are timestamps from today and yesterday in the column).

Have I made a syntax error? Am I crazy? Are there gnomes in my DB messing with my query? Please help! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the datatype for that field is `datetime` or `smalldatetime` then `LIKE` won't work as expected.

You could do a `DATEPART` function or `BETWEEN`, like:

```
WHERE DATEPART(Year, column1) = 2011
AND DATEPART(Month, column1) = 7
AND DATEPART(Day, column1) IN (7, 8)
```

or

`WHERE column1 BETWEEN '2011-07-07' AND '2011-07-08'`

Bear in mind `BETWEEN` is inclusive.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much for the explanation. I knew it had to be simple, I just wasn't seeing it, but that's exactly right.

Comment: @Josh - happy to help.  Whenever you have unexpected behavior one of the first things you can do is check your datatypes!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
select column1 from table1 with(nolock)
where Cast(column1 as DateTime) between '2011-07-07' AND '2011-07-08'
order by column1 desc
```